# Preventing Mule servers from reprocessing same information from a database

Tags: java, mule

I am working on a Mule application which reads a series of database records generates reports and posts them to a number of HTTP locations. Unfortunately, the servers are not clustered, so it is possible that both servers could read the records and post them multiple times which is undesirable. Could someone suggest the simplest way to prevent all three Mule servers reading the database, generating the reports and sending them off??

Comment: I'd say don't bother. This should be dealt with by proper design of your infrastructure to prevent the double-up of processing from occurring. If you cannot fix that, then leave it up to the consumer to deal with the payloads.

Comment: I have no control over fixing the infrastructure.  Unfortunately, duplicate reports are unacceptable.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer - use cluster.
Long answer - there is no magic in this world. If you don't use cluster which coordinates your efforts then you should do it by yourself. Since servers are not in cluster they should communicate somehow to prevent duplication. Cluster is the best answer and it is designed to do so. Without cluster - do it "manually".

There are many ways to do so. Main point is that it should be the only one place responsible for coordination (may I say cluster? :)  - the best way IMHO it is database - it is one place which is common for all these servers. simplest way is to mark processed records and process only unprocessed ones. How you do this - extra table or extra field - it's up to you.